# My form submits even with empty required fields

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a form on my page that fades into something else with a thank you picture and the like. All my `inputs` are `required`, but the fade still occurs when you don't fill out everything in the form.

I think it's because I'm using an `input` element with `type="image"`, because when I'm using a normal button element, the fade doesn't occur unless I fill out everything.

Extra info: The form does work in the backend, it's just that it shouldn't allow the change when not every input has been filled out.

HTML (form)

```
<form id="form" action="/" method="POST">
    <div>
        <div class="inputName">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="inputEmail">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" id="email" name="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="inputSubject">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <textarea name="message" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>

    <input type="image" id="send" src='https://i.imgur.com/Tt39rjV.png' onmouseover="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/81fmcHg.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/Tt39rjV.png';" border="0" alt="Send" />
</form>
```

EDIT: 
Probably also important, my Javascript/jQuery that does the fading:

```
$('#message').click(function(e){    
    $('.contact1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('.contact2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#send').click(function(e){    
    $('.contact2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('.contact3').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it's because I'm using an input element with type="image", because when I'm using a normal button element, the fade doesn't occur unless I fill out 
>   everything.

That's exactly the point. If you do that, you will have to validate it yourself. Use a `button` with `type="submit"` and put your image inside of that. Also, wire your fade logic to the form's `submit` event instead of just the click.

`<input type="image">` is meant for use cases where click coordinates should be captured.

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
   e.target.textContent = "Submitted!";
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="/" method="POST">
    <div>
        <div class="inputName">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="inputEmail">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" id="email" name="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="inputSubject">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <textarea name="message" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>

    <button type="submit">
       <img style="width: 20px" src='https://i.imgur.com/Tt39rjV.png' onmouseover="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/81fmcHg.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/Tt39rjV.png';"/>
    </button>
</form>
```

<sub>(Furthermore, i believe that jQuery should never be used.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

**1.You can set the id of the textbox that is required to txtBox and use the 
  following code-**

```
$(function(){
$("#my-form").validate();
});

$(function(){
if($("#txtBox").val() != ""){
$('form[name="required-form"]').submit(function(event){
    $('#required-form').fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $('#optional-form').fadeIn("slow");
}
else{alert('Please fill in the required fields');}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on W3schools.com 's Try it editor.
It worked fine and also it was validating empty fields when that button was clicked

See the image [W3schools tryit editor results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DK6i.png)